# SQL find linked records where none are flagged as default

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a doctor table and a locations table. Each doctor can have multiple locations but only one location per doctor can be flagged as the default location. I am trying to find any doctors who do not have a location flagged as default. The join is doctors.ID to locations.doctor_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `not exists` clause.

```
select * from doctor d
where not exists 
( select 1 from locations
  where locations.doctor_id = d.id
  and locations.default =1
)
```

another way to do is using `left join`

```
select * from doctor d
left join locations l
on l.doctor_id = d.id
and l.default =1
where l.doctor_id is NULL
```